Shopware 6 background-image src-set
{% block page_content_section %}
<div class="cms-section {{ sectionClasses|join(' ') }}"
     style="{% if sectionBgColor %}background-color: {{ sectionBgColor }};{% endif %}{% if sectionBgImg %}background-image: url({{ sectionBgImg }});background-size: {{ section.backgroundMediaMode }};{% endif %}">

Is there a way to get the generated thumbnail for "sectionBgImg" for a better page performance. When I set a Background in Shopware Backend it will load the big image also on mobile.
Edit:

To clear things up: Usually shopware will include images via "sw_thumbnails" to optimize pictures for mobile devices. With the background image of sections it won't load the generated thumbnails of the image you set(see image). Is there a way to optimize this?

From your question it's not absolutely clear wether you want different images based on screen size / device or only the smaller thumbnail.

thx for feedback, tried to clear things up

I found that Shopware is doing it a different way, when you add a background image to a CMS-Block. I adapted this approach from this file:
\vendor\shopware\storefront\Resources\views\storefront\section\cms-section-block-container.html.twig

Code for a mobile optimized background picture in sections.
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/page/content/detail.html.twig' %}
{% block page_content_section %}
<div class="cms-section {{ sectionClasses|join(' ') }}"
        style="{% if sectionBgColor %}background-color: {{ sectionBgColor }};{% endif %}">


    {% if section.backgroundMedia %}
        {% sw_thumbnails 'cms-block-background' with {
            media: section.backgroundMedia,
            attributes: {
                class: "cms-block-background media-mode--" ~ section.backgroundMediaMode
            },
            sizes: {
                'sm': '400px',
                'md': '800px',
                'xl': '1920px'
            }
        } %}
    {% endif %}

    {% sw_include "@Storefront/storefront/section/cms-section-" ~ section.type ~ ".html.twig" %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

The CSS, please edit as needed for your Theme
.cms-section {

&.bg-image {
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
}

.cms-block-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    object-fit: none;
    font-family: 'object-fit: none;';

    &.media-mode--contain {
        object-fit: contain;
        font-family: 'object-fit: contain;';
    }

    &.media-mode--cover {
        object-fit: cover;
        font-family: 'object-fit: cover;';
    }
}


is there a way we can use two or more images in media?

Yes, the HTML <picture> approach is a very good when it comes to responsive image handling. You should use it over the old school background-image.
In your case you need the media entity of that image. sectionBgImg is just a wrapper for the media URL.
The variable for the entire media entity is section.backgroundMedia.
https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/4cc2e1428a9139fe75c5ea1468b5cb52bb272134/src/Storefront/Resources/views/storefront/page/content/detail.html.twig#L8
So you can use section.backgroundMedia with sw_thumbnails:
{% sw_thumbnails 'my-section-bg' with {
    media: section.backgroundMedia
} %}

For further explanation of thumbnail handling:
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/use-media-thumbnails.html#working-with-sw-thumbnail

Yes this is somewhat I was looking for. Just a bit more. I found a way to get it done.
